# Can't access MAAS web interface

Tags: server, maas

I'm currently using a virtual machine to run ubuntu server. I installed maas on it. I got this error everytime.

```
The requested URL /MAAS was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.105 Port 80
```

I tried to access the web interface. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: This is unusual. It may mean that installation failed somehow, or that the setup conflicts with something else that you have running, such as another web application. See if you can find something relevant in the logs: /var/log/maas/* and /var/log/apache2/error.log (and perhaps if your requests are coming through in /var/log/apache2/access.log). Also, do you have a file /etc/apache2/conf.d/maas-http.conf installed? If that were missing somehow then you might get this kind of failure.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like something went wrong when you installed the package.  Please make sure that the package is installed by checking if the file `/usr/share/maas/maas/urls.py` is present on your system.  Then you need to make sure that the apache configuration is properly installed by making sure that `/etc/apache2/conf.d/maas-http.conf` is a valid link.

As a last resort option, you can purge the package and reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge maas
sudo apt-get install maas
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change ur url from this

```
http://"localhost"/maas
```

to

```
http://"localhost"/MAAS
```

this might be funny but it actually worked trust me

try the url without the quotes `"`

Answer (score 1):

I do no if this is the right answer to your question but I faced the same kind of problem : The MaaS web user interface became unrecheable after changing the IP address of my controller.

The solution was to reconfigure a lot of MaaS related packages :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep maas
```

Here is the output :

```
maas                    install
maas-cli                install
maas-cluster-controller install
maas-common             install
maas-region-controller  install
...
```

I reconfigured the packages :

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
$ sudo reboot
```

... All works fine now !

Hope it helps.